# Show Toast if record not matched

Tags: android

I am using addTextChangedListener(...) to get matched string using Filter in arraylist. 
I can filter the matched string easily but, i want if entered string doesn't matched with the arraylist records then show toast that record not found.

this is my addTextChangedListener() Method

```
etserach.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        String st = etserach.getText().toString();
        if (!s.equals("") && s.length() > 0) {
            adapter_filter.filter(st);
        } else {
            adapter_filter.filter(st);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is filter() Method from adapter

```
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    resultArrayshort.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        resultArrayshort.addAll(citylistNew);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < citylistNew.size(); i++) {
            String fullname = citylistNew.get(i).getClientNameE();
            if (fullname.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                resultArrayshort.add(citylistNew.get(i));
            }
          /*  else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Record not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } */
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: what you want ? Toast syntax or logic ? why it is not showing ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hi, thnx for the rpl, let's suppose  {"abc","acb","aab"} these 3 record in my arraylist and i m entering "aaQ" in a filtering editText then its should show msg that "record not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @nidhi after for loop check the size of resultArray, if it is empty then show toast

Comment: hi, thnx for the rpl and my arraylist is not empty ,my record is not matching for ex. {"abc","acb","aab"} these 3 record in my arraylist and i m entering "aaQ" in a filtering editText then its should show msg that "record not found"

Comment: @nidhi you must try my  answer

Comment: implement  fiter in adapter , so that in publishResults() you can check for empty list. In adapter we can implement filter

Comment: hey @shanmugam thank uhh sooooo muchhhh uhh solved my problem with ur first ans only i tried it again and its done now.

Answer (score 0):

after notifydatasetchanged check size of resultArrayshort if found empty then show toast

```
if(resultArrayshort.isEmpty()){

//show toast

}
```

Comment: @nidhi i think i have answered it first